# How to export mapBoxGL map?

Tags: javascript, export, leaflet, mapbox-gl

I am using mapboxGL for rendering maps on web page, i would like to export the map as image including GeoJSON data that's been plotted on the map. 
I tried using leaflet plugin, but it does not render clusters and other custom html which is shown on the map as popup or annotation.

Even if i try to do this on server, like using phantomjs, then it(phantomjs) does not support webgl..
am stuck and don't know how do i do this, any suggestions ?

Comment: Mapbox GL JS renders to a `<canvas>` element. There are canvas2png solutions out there. Note that you'll need to set `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` in the options when initializing the map.

Answer (score 2):

MpboxGL can export extremely well, and easily! Anything you add to the map is exportable, which is really awesome.

in the map declaration, make sure you set `preserveDrawingBuffer` to true

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: myawesomestyle,
  zoom: 8,
  bearing: 0,
  pitch: 0,
  center: [13, 52.35],
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});
```

I like to use CanvasToBlob and FileSaver to do the inner steps, so in the doc head include the two libs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/canvas-toblob/0.1/canvas-toBlob.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

and tie it together with a little print function

```
function printMap() {
  map.getCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
    saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
  })
}
```